# ColumnStore Index Scan is not happening in batch mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan, columnstore

In my DB there are some column store indexes and these tables used in procedures. When executing the procedures in my development server, the execution mode for column store indices is coming in batch mode. But when i move these to production, these becomes row wise execution mode. Is any Server settings impacting for these. Can any one help me.

Note that both servers are SQL 2014

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your queries are running in parallel (MADOP >= 2), this is the most common cause for loosing Batch Execution Mode.
The other one would be the lack of working memory, check if the queries are getting enough memory in the grants.